# htaccess URL rewrites with multiple Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

thanks for your time. I thought I knew how to do this but I've tried dozens of permutations and I'm failing.

I want to replace missing images with a placeholder image of the appropriate size. The real images are organized into directories by size. Directory names are just numbers such as: 320, 640, 960, 1080.... Each size directory contains an appropriately sized image, all called "toc-placeholder.jpg"

Sample of missing image URL

```
/img/toc/640/toc-074.jpg
```

Path to placeholder image

```
/img/toc/640/toc-placeholder.jpg
```

```
## PLACEHOLDER FOR MISSING TOC IMAGES ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
## REPLACE ANY MISSING UNDER THE "TOC" DIRECTORY WITH ONE SPECIFIC IMAGE##
RewriteRule ^img/toc/* img/toc/960/toc-placeholder.jpg [L]
## REPLACE MISSING IMG WITH IMAGE FROM THE SAME SIZE DIRECTORY##
##RewriteRule ^img/toc/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ img/toc/$1/toc-placeholder.jpg [L]
```

The first rule (the active one) works fine. Id like to replace it with the second rule (the one that is commented out) so I can redirect to a placeholder of the appropriate size in each case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That does not really make sense: `^img/toc/*`, use `^img/toc/` instead, or `^img/toc/?`, depending on whether you also want to replace requests to the folder itself.

Comment: Although some details could be discussed in your implementation it should work, especially the last, commented rule (which is the one you ask about, I assume). So there must be some other issue here, not the rule itself. Are you sure that configuration file gets considered at all by the http server? How did you make sure? What does your http server's error log file say about those requests? What actual result do you get for such requests (check in your browser's development console)?

Comment: I agree that it should work. I'm going to look for conflicts with other rules & post a new reply with what I find. In the meantime I would be interested to hear what you mean about details in my implementation. I would also like some clarity on my use of `^img/toc/*` vs the suggested options. Maybe the * is not needed.  Does the ?denote a missing file in the context?

Comment: The htaccess file is definitely being recognized and implemented. All of the other rules work & the dumber version of this particular rule works. The browser console only shows the 404 error for the missing image. the access & error log files don't seem to show anything whatsoever in regards to the missing images. I did a quick check for conflicts by literally removing all other rules from the .htaccess file & got the same result. I'm still stumped.

Comment: That the access and error log files show nothing about those requests is impossible if the requests are actually done.

Comment: About your question here in the comment about what a "*" or a "?" actually does I would like to ask you to learn about the basics of regular expressions. That is well documented and there are many good tutorials out there. No sense in repeating that here. If you are using tools you need to be able to use them. If you use a tool that uses regular expressions, then you need to have a basic understanding of how those work.

Comment: That was not my question & it's a pretty condescending way to communicate with someone who's trying to learn something. I have enough understanding that I've written about 120 lines worth of rules & conditions for this particular file that all work together & do all sorts of great stuff. I was more curious why the / needs to  be optional... but thats a side issue since that rule was never the one in question. Maybe my question about the ./+ could be cleared up by referencing your earlier assumption that directories could only contain images & that file extensions would never be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working.

It occurred to me that the expression: `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` alone might not account for file extensions. I tried to get a . into the that expression but had trouble so I modified the line to add file extensions thusly:

```
## PLACEHOLDER FOR MISSING TOC IMAGES ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ 
## RewriteRule ^img/toc/* img/toc/960/toc-placeholder.jpg [L]
## PLACEHOLDER FROM APPROPRIATE SIZE DIRECTORY (NOT WORKING) ##
RewriteRule ^img/toc/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ img/toc/$1/toc-placeholder.jpg [L]
```

Seems like there's an easier way to do this if anyone wants to share. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can do away with your second RewriteCond here, the RewriteRule pattern already checks that the URL ends with one of those suffixes.

Comment: Please do not post additional information as an "answer" to the question. There is an "edit" button below your question, _use it_ . Add a clearly marked update to the question.

Comment: About your rule: You do not actually need this. Something like `^/?img/toc/(\d+)/.+` is perfectly fine, since I assume that this folder only contains images. You do not need to capture the actual file name. You are not using that anyway. You only need to match the path prefix.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. That's true. In this iteration, the second condition is redundant. It looks like it would still be needed if I were to take the advice from arkascha & use his much shorter version. Thanks arkascha. I figured there would be a smarter way. You're right. I don't really need the file name, its a relic of older iterations. I still have a lot to learn so I'm a little confused by the /.+ in your version. Can you please explain?